# kendo-angular-dropdowns combobox.component.d.ts

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to use the controls and everything seems to work.  Just one control I'm not able to use and that's the dropdown.

I'm getting the error

> "Build:';' expected in combobox.component.d.ts

This is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "angular-quickstart",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
        "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
        "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
        "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
        "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
        "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "postinstall": "typings install",
        "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
        "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "typings": "typings",
        "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "licenses": [
        {
          "type": "MIT",
          "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
        }
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~2.0.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.2",
        "@angular/core": "~2.0.2",
        "@angular/forms": "~2.0.2",
        "@angular/http": "~2.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.2",
        "@angular/router": "~3.0.2",
        "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.2",
        "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.10.3",
        "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.14.1",
        "@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "^1.26.1",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "systemjs": "0.19.39",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
        "typescript": "^2.0.3",
        "typings": "^1.4.0",
        "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
        "http-server": "^0.9.0",
        "tslint": "^3.15.1",
        "lodash": "^4.16.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
        "karma": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "^3.3.0",
        "rimraf": "^2.5.4"
      },
      "repository": {}
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've got a second question.  Can you extend the quickstart to include all controls?(Now only the button is in there)

Kind Regards.

Comment: Try using `"@progress/kendo-popup-common": "^0.1.1",` dropdown is working for me with angular2 version 2.0.0 and kendo-angular-dropdowns version 0.14.1

Comment: Also can you share please your systemjs.config.js?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in typing as the error message says "Build:';' expected in combobox.component.d.ts. Check the typing file to see if a ';' is missing.